# Button could not be tapped - UIAutomation

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, ios-ui-automation

I am attempting to create script that will automate sign in process (to login). However, when I run script it says that 'could not be tapped'. Below is what I have written so far:

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var app = target.frontMostApp();
var appWindow = app.mainWindow();
var settingsButton = appWindow.buttons()["CloseVector"];
var settingsView = app.mainWindow().staticTexts()["Settings"]

UIALogger.logStart("Sign in test")


settingsButton.tap(); 
target.delay(1); 

if (settingsView.isValid())
{
    UIALogger.logPass("Correct View");
}
else
{
    UIALogger.logFail("Wrong View");
}
```

Comment: One thing that's definitely going to go wrong here is that you're evaluating the reference to the `settingsView` before you tap the settings button.